# FabricJs - large image movement is laggy

Tags: angular, fabricjs

I am adding an image to canvas in the following way:

```
  public addImageToCanvas(imageUrl: string){
    fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrl,(img)=>{
        var dataURL = img.toDataURL({});
        fabric.Image.fromURL(dataURL, (imgFromDataUrl)=>{
            this.canvas.add(imgFromDataUrl);
            this.canvas.setActiveObject(imgFromDataUrl);
        })
        },{ crossOrigin: 'anonymous' })
}
```

I do it in two steps because I want to store the canvas JSON later and i want it to have the image as blob, not as link.

When I move the image on canvas it's laggy. I tried experimenting with .objectCache property but it has no influence on performace.

Has anyone faced similliar problem and fixed this performace issue?

Comment: How large is large?

Comment: 1200x1000px is enough to slow down the performance